# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Vue.js

Tags: node.js, api, express, sockets, vue.js

I am trying to display a series of articles from a Google Alerts RSS Feed on my Vue.js application. My back end is Express.js.

Is my back end correct or do adjustments have to be made? If not, do I need a certain script in my index.html or something like "Vue.use(socket.io) " in my main.js?

This is my [code](https://github.com/RyanMurph17/DisplayRSSFeed).

I receive these errors when I run my application:

[Error in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyYdN.png)

Comment: you forgot the IO code :D https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

Comment: Thank you! Where do I place this in my code? https://github.com/RyanMurph17/DisplayRSSFeed

Comment: in nodejs server's code https://github.com/RyanMurph17/DisplayRSSFeed/blob/master/src/components/index.js